# Add action perfom and validate input components in java?

Tags: java, swing, jtable, tablemodel, defaulttablemodel

I am designing a swing interface which looks like this: [image]

After filling information in text field and hitting "add" button, all information will appear in the table below.Here is my code for doing that:

```
 private void AddActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                    
    Vector record = new Vector();
    record.add(Name);
    record.add(Email);
    record.add(Address);
    record.add(PhoneNumber);

    String name = this.Name.getText();
    String email = this.Email.getText();
    String address = this.Address.getText();
    String phone = this.PhoneNumber.getText();
    System.out.println(phone);
    DefaultTableModel model = (DefaultTableModel)tblCustomer.getModel();
    model.insertRow(ERROR, record);

}
```

But when i hit the "add" button,nothing happen except these exception

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 64 > 4
at java.util.Vector.insertElementAt(Vector.java:598)
at javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel.insertRow(DefaultTableModel.java:374)
at NewJFrame.AddActionPerformed(NewJFrame.java:290)
at NewJFrame.access$300(NewJFrame.java:16)
at NewJFrame$4.actionPerformed(NewJFrame.java:155)
at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2022)
at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2348)
at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:402)
at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:259)
at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(BasicButtonListener.java:252)
at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6535)
at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3324)
at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6300)
at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2236)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4891)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2294)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4713)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4888)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4525)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4466)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2280)
at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2750)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4713)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:758)
at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(EventQueue.java:97)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:709)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:703)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:86)
at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:731)
at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:729)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:728)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:201)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:93)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:82)
```

Can someone point out what is the problem? Also how can you Validate Input components before inserting into the table ?Example:if the name text field is null,it will send an error message  for user.Thanks in advance and sorry for my english.

Comment: Don't post a picture of the IDE. The IDE has nothing to do with your question and makes it hard to see the relevant parts of the form. Just post a picture of the form if you post any image. That way will actually be able to see what the form looks like.

Comment: as an addition to what @camickr said, post the errors you are getting so we can indentify the problem.

Comment: Fixed.Thank you for your advice

Comment: And what is "ERROR"?

Comment: For better help sooner, post a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/).

Comment: Repeating @camickr (but louder) **Don't post a picture of the IDE.** The text of those errors can be copied. Just drag the mouse across them and type Ctrl+C. See also [What is a stack trace, and how can I use it to debug my application errors?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3988788/418556)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 64 > 4
>
> model.insertRow(ERROR, record);

You can't just randomly insert a row anywhere in the table. You only have 4 rows in the TableModel so you can only insert rows at index 0, 1, 2, 3, 4.

I suggest you should just use the:

```
model.addRow( record );
```

method. Then the row will be added to the end of the table no matter how many rows are in the table.

Comment: Thank you for your answer.I wonder how can we add row at the begin for the table ?

Answer (score 1):

That's because you're not adding anything to your `record` vector, you should add the variables after you get the text from your fields, try this:

```
private void AddActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                    
    Vector record = new Vector();

    String name = this.Name.getText();
    String email = this.Email.getText();
    String address = this.Address.getText();
    String phone = this.PhoneNumber.getText();

    record.add(name);
    record.add(email);
    record.add(address);
    record.add(phone);

    System.out.println(phone);
    DefaultTableModel model = (DefaultTableModel)tblCustomer.getModel();
    model.insertRow(ERROR, record);

}
```

Comment: Still nothing happen except a lot of exceptions

Comment: Please modify your question with the errors you are getting, so we can determine what is the problem.

Comment: JTable / DefaultTableModel accepts null value, you can to add empty Vector, but ERROR has value at 64, (and) or DefaultTableModel is (fixed at) 4 rows